# "Pink material" problem with Vuforia Model Target and Unity Universal Render Pipeline (URP)

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, urp

I created a new Unity 3D project, which uses the new Universal Render Pipeline (using the official project template). I also added the latest version of Vuforia Engine AR and added a Vuforia Model Target Database by importing a `.unitypackage` file exported from the Vuforia Developer Portal. Then I added the ARCamera and a Model Target GameObject to the scene.

Now to the problem. When I enable the Universal Render Pipeline under **Projects Settings > Graphics** by selecting **URP-Balanced** from the list at **Scriptable Render Pipeline Settings**, all materials of my model target game object turn pink.

This seems to be a common problem with the **Universal Render Pipeline (URP)** and I read that you have to change the Shaders that are associated with the Materials that are used on the model. So I looked at my assets browser and went to **Resources > VuforiaModels > my_model >Materials** and tried to change everything to `Universal render Pipeline/Lit` but it still shows as pink.

As this issue reproducibly only affects (new) projects with the Universal Render Pipeline - but not the Built-in Render Pipeline his boils down to a yes/no question to the Vuforia team:

**Does the Vuforia Model Target Generator support the Universal Render Pipeline?**

Software used:

- macOS Ventura 13.5.1 (Apple M1 Chip)
- Unity 2022.3.8f1 (latest LTS as of now)
- Vuforia Engine AR 10.17.4 (latest version as of now)

Note: We were instructed by Vuforia to ask all technical questions first right here, as the Vuforia's classic forum has been retired into read-only mode.

Comment: This is exactly what it should do. As you havent mentioned converting any materials. There are (on pc anyway) options to convert materials

Comment: Thanks, but the preview model still shows as pink. I don't see the 3d model as game object in my scene graph. It gets automatically added by Vuforia when using the Vuforia Model Target game object. There are two scripts on that game object called Model Target Behaviour (Script) and Model Target Preview (Script). One of those is probably adding the preview model. But I can't access those scripts. I guess Vuforia doesn't fully support the Universal Render Pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

From information on the old forum here https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/feature-discussions/other-features/unity-universal-render-pipeline-urp-integration : URP is not officially supported. Some of the shaders in the Vuforia Unity extensions are not compatible with URP.

I would recommend to file a feature request here https://github.com/PTCInc/vuforia-engine

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the linked forums post doesn't contain an official statement on that matter. There is talk of **some limitations** which boils down to the following statement from the release notes: "Setting the far clip plane to a large number can cause the video background image to flicker when using the URP in combination with GLES3". I was hoping for a clear answer concerning the Model Target Generator. My solution is to just stick with the built-in render pipeline of Unity.

Comment: Yes you are right. My understanding is that if you have some shaders working wit the built-in pipeline they have to be ported to URP. This does not seem to have happened for the Vuforia extension. That's why I suggested to file a feature request on the github repo.